# Azure Cosmos DB Search with Contains and lower/ upper function

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query cosmosDB where would like to search the first name with SQL 'like' feature, also for case insensitivity i'm using cosmos DBs' 'lower' function.

e.g.  SELECT * FROM c where contains (lower(c.lastName), "abc")) // Request Charge = 1660+

I observed Request Charge for this query is around 1660+ but when I use normal query without 'Contains' and 'lower' function the Request Charge is just '8'

e.g.  SELECT * FROM c where c.lastName = "abc" // Request Charge = 8

Please help to understand what's causing the huge difference in Request Charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query with `contains` is effectively doing a **freetext** search and will have to scan all documents.

The second query is using an **exact** match and thus will just use an index and cost less.

And to besides the cost of the actual query path the result set of the first query could be much greater than the second as the second is always contained within the first but the first could match many more, e.g. abcd, cabcd.

If you're looking to search across a lot of text columns then it is worth looking at one of two options.

1. If you are searching for whole words and the columns are not too
   long then you could tokenize the columns into matching fields
2. The more robust option would be to look at using Azure search in
       combination with Cosmos DB

This [advice is from the azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/searching-for-text-with-documentdb/)

Comment: Yes the First query will definitely have more results but at the cost it's running is much much higher, it also slows the response. I understand that it's doing entire scan of collection (size of collection 1 million and can grow till 10 million), but **is there any better way to handle this** as we have a requirement were 6-7 fields will be part of Query filter (like First Name, last name, city, Email, etc).